# How many elements has the multiplicative group of this ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem which asks to find how many elements  the multiplicative group of a ring $R$ has. It is defined as follows: $R= \Big\{ \left(\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{matrix}\right) | a,b \in \Bbb Z_3\Big\}$

To look for how many elements the multiplicative group has is not the same as to look for how many elements the general linear group has? Anyway, I know that with $\Bbb Z_n$ it is possible to use the Euler function to know how many elements the corresponding multiplicative group has. How should I proceed in this case? Any help?

Comment: Check if this group is abelian first.

Comment: @Radost Yes, It is

Comment: Determine the number of matrices with nonzero determinant.

Comment: In this case you know that it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: @Radost how can I find $n$?

Comment: Two matrices are equal if they are equal component-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only nine element of this ring, and the invertible ones satisfy $a^2+b^2\neq 0$. So write out the matrices and check the condition (You will find that there are 8 such matrices).

Comment: I've done this before. Your answer, however, is useful to me in confirming that they are 8 invertible matrices. Thank you.